# Help typecasting a String Array of bytes to actual bytes

Tags: java, type-conversion

I have a string that looks like this: ["1011000", "1000010", "1001101", "1000011"].

My argument is coming from elsewhere so it needs to be this way.

I need to typecast this to a real byte array.

Here's my method:

```
public void send(String[] payloadarr)  throws IOException { 
    byte [] payload = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < payloadarr.length; i++) {
        byte x = (byte) payloadarr[i];
        payload[i] = x;
    }
    //do byte stuff with payload
}
```

It doesn't work, however.  Complains about inconvertable types String to byte.

Can anyone help me with this typecasting?

Comment: Did you try, [`String.getBytes()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29) or [`String.getBytes(ENCODING)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29)? I made this a comment because I'm not aware of your requirements.

Comment: Do you actually mean that you have an *array* of strings?

Comment: That is probably the wrong answer.  Those strings look very much as if they are intended to be base-2 numeric representations of bytes.  Yes - `payloadarr` is an ARRAY of strings.

Comment: BTW: This is not type _casting_ but type conversion, or better, data parsing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDITED:** Thanks to @Gabe for idea to change from `Integer.parseInt` to `Byte.parseByte`

You can use [Byte.parseByte(String s, int radix)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) - your radix being `2` (ie base 2)

Here's a handy method to convert an array of String to `byte[]`:

```
public static byte[] stringsToBytes(String[] payloadarr) {
    byte[] payload = new byte[payloadarr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < payloadarr.length; i++) {
        payload[i] = Byte.parseByte(payloadarr[i], 2);
    }
    return payload;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringsToBytes(new String[] { "1011000", "1000010", "1001101", "1000011" })));
}
```

Output:

```
[88, 66, 77, 67]
```

Comment: @brian: If your problem is solved, accept the best answer (there is an "accept" button for you beside the answer).

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell from your question, but it sounds like you really want

```
byte x = Byte.parseByte(payloadarr[i], 2);
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Looks like the other folks proffering answers didn't realize Byte.parseByte() existed. This avoids a cast, and while parsing as an int and then doing the narrowing cast does do the right thing with the sign bit, it might be a little surprising to newcomers when they find that e.g. Integer.parseInt("11011011")==219 but (byte)Integer.parseInt("11011011")==-37.

Comment: @prodicus: Not to mention which a `(byte)Integer.parseInt("100000000")` returns 0 instead of throwing an exception!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this using (just) type casts.

You need to use `Integer.parseInt(String, int)` where the `int` is 2.  That will give you an `int` which you need to cast to a `byte`.

```
public void send(String[] payloadarr)  throws IOException { 
    byte [] payload = new byte[payloadarr.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < payloadarr.length; i++) {
        payload[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(payloadarr[i], 2);
    }
    //do byte stuff with payload
}
```

---

Notes

- The above method will throw `NumberFormatException` if any of the components of `payloadarr` is not a binary string.
- I fixed the initialization of `payload` ...